# Simulated Annealing Parameter Tuning

Tags: optimization, monte-carlo, computational-statistics, simulated-annealing

My question concerns parameter tuning for simulated annealing (SA). I've the following toy equation

$$
y = (x^2+x) \times cos(2x) + 20 \text{ if } x \in (-10, 10)
$$

My problem is that the solution bounces around often between a local maximum and global maximum. I believe this may be due to my choices in parameters, but not being an expert with SA, I'm not sure how to set the temperature and update it over time. I feel there is also an issue with the choice for proposal distribution from which the candidate is drawn from. Suggestions for improvement with examples would be helpful!

The SA algorithm goes as follows

1. Generate an initial candidate solution $x$
2. Get an initial Temperature $T > 0$.
3. `for i in range(N)` (`N` = number of iterations)

   1. Sample $\zeta \sim g(\zeta)$ where $g$ is a symmetrical distribution.
   2. The new candidate solution is $x' = x \pm \zeta$
   3. Accept the candidate solution, $x = x'$ with probability $p = exp\left( 
      \Delta h/ T_i \right)$, else accept $x = x$
   4. Update the temperature (cooling)

References:

- [Introduction to Monte Carlo Methods](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa) by Robert and Casella
- [Optimization by Simulated Annealing: An Experimental Evaluation; Part I, Graph Partitioning](http://faculty.washington.edu/aragon/pubs/annealing-pt1.pdf)

Here is my implementation in Python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def h(x):
    if x < -10 or x > 10:
        y = 0
    else:
        y = (x**2+x)*np.cos(2*x) + 20
    return y

hv = np.vectorize(h)


def SA(search_space, func, T):
    scale = np.sqrt(T) # suggested by Robert-Casella Intro to MC
    start = -0.4 # initial starting value; constant for testing purposes
    x = start * 1 # copy the starting value
    for i in range(1000):
        prop = x + np.random.normal() * scale # generate proposal from symmetrical distribution
        p = max(0, min(1, np.exp( (func(prop) - func(x))/ T))) # probability of acceptance
        if np.random.rand() < p:
            #print((prop,func(prop)), (x, func(x)))    
            x = prop # accept proposal
        T = 0.9 *T # cooling
    return (start,x), (func(start), func(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    X = np.linspace(-15, 15, num=100)
    plt.ion()
    for it in range(20):
        plt.cla()
        x1, y1 = SA(X, h, T = 8)
        print(x1, y1)

        plt.plot(X, hv(X))
        plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='x')
        plt.plot(x1, y1)
        plt.title('Run:{}, 1000 iterations'.format(it))
        plt.pause(0.5)

    plt.ioff()
```

[image: Local Maxima]

[image: Global Maximum]

Comment: From what you are describing, it is just an optimization. Any reason why you call it parameter tuning?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking through the code: `SA` function is always called with the same value of temperature, $T=8$. The statement `T = 0.9 *T # cooling` does nothing, since it appears just before one exits the function and forgets its local variables.

The simplest solution is to move the temperature schedule into the main loop, something like:

````
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    X = np.linspace(-15, 15, num=100)
    plt.ion()
    T = 8
    for it in range(20):
        plt.cla()
        x1, y1 = SA(X, h, T = T)
        T = 0.9 * T #or simply T *= 0.9
        print(x1, y1)

        plt.plot(X, hv(X))
        plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='x')
        plt.plot(x1, y1)
        plt.title('Run:{}, 1000 iterations'.format(it))
        plt.pause(0.5)
```
````

Comment: i did not test the OP's code, but inside the SA function the cooling is handled properly, he just calls always the SA function w/ the same starting temperature.

Comment: @CzylabsonAsa not sure how your comment differs from my answer.

Comment: do you mean that there is no proper cooling inside the SA? i tested it and except the bouncing it is ok. a possible solution for the "bouncing": using different scale (domain specific) and different schedule and returning not the actual x but the best one.